# AngularJs 2: How to debug a service call? (es6 syntax)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ecmascript-6, angular2-services

**THE SITUATION:**

I am just learning Angular2. I wanted to debug the call to a service.

The service has been properly called, as I can see in the view.

I also want to log to content of variable that hold the result, but it is not working as i would except.

**THE SERVICE:**

```
export class ListService 
{
    getList() 
    {
        return Promise.resolve(LIST);
    }
}
```

**THE CALL** (from the list component):

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit
{
    list: Item[];

    constructor(
        private _router: Router, 
        private _listService: ListService
    ) { }


    getList() 
    {
        this._listService.getList().then(list => this.list = list);
    }

    ngOnInit() 
    {
        this.getList();
    }

}
```

**LOG ATTEMPT 1:**

`list` is the variable containing the list of items. In the view it properly show the content. So i would expect to log it and see its content.

```
getList() 
{
    this._listService.getList().then(list => this.list = list);
    console.log(list)
}
```

But when i get this error instead:

```
EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: list is not defined in [null]
```

**LOG ATTEMPT 2:**

Trying to get the correct syntax:

```
getList() 
{
    this._listService.getList().then(list => this.list = list);
    console.log(this.list)
}
```

There are no errors now. But in the console it shows `undefined`. 
But the service has already been called. So it should contain the content

**THE QUESTION:**

Considering that i am using Angular2 - Ecmascript 2016

What is the proper syntax to log the call of a service?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Well this is more specific about Angular2 syntax

Comment: The main issue is the same, this is not specific to any syntax, it's about how async task work and how you can work with it in javascript (BTW this is not Angular2 syntax but Ecmascript 6 the new Javascript standard)

Comment: Yes i got it. But if you just want to know just syntax for Angular2 you will find here the answer straightly.

Comment: Well i edited the title. In order to make it more specific to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact `this.list` is set within the callback registered in the `then` method. So you should use something like that:

```
getList() 
{
  this._listService.getList().then(list => {
    this.list = list;
    console.log(list);
    console.log(this.list);
  });
}
```

If you put the `console.log(this.list);` right the promise, the result won't be probably there so `this.list` probably doesn't set...